# Any good books on math puzzles and nim games?

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

Are there any good books on nim games, math puzzles, and games where players take turns, player A moves somehow, player B moves somehow, etc? I tried using Engel's book by it is a bit too advanced for me and I'm having trouble understanding it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out which book you are referring to, so I can't judge the level, but I love Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays: Volume 1, Berlekamp and Conway